# HVAC indoor unit makes buzzing sound

Tags: hvac, furnace

Not 100% sure if this sound was always there, sounds like an old capacitor sound. AC works fine.

https://youtube.com/shorts/nEk8XfcMSJM

[image]

Is this normal? How can I fix it?

Comment: that is a click, not a buzz ... sounds like a relay activating

Comment: It's buzzing after click. It's barely noticeable on video, try to increase the volume of the sound.